# Nginx & url rewriting

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have a redirection:

```
server {
    server_name     mydomain.com;
    rewrite ^(.*)   http://myanotherdomain.net/image$1 permanent;
}
```

Everything is ok when I go in mydomain.com/exemple, but how to point mydomain.com where I want ?

I want:
mydomain.com/test -> myanotherdomain.net/image/test (or other than "test") and
mydomain.com -> myanotherdomain.net

Is it possible ?

Comment: So you want everything except root request to be redirected to `/image/`?

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    server_name mydomain.com;
    location = / {
        return 301 http://myanotherdomain.net;
    }
    location / {
        return 301 http://myanotherdomain.net/image$request_uri;
    }
}
```